# BackgroundWorker Event Handlers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` object that I instantiated to perform a DB process on a background thread ansynchronously. I have event handlers for `DoWor`k and `RunWorkerCompleted`.

I can tell that the `BackgroundWorker` is disposing of itself because I added a `MessageBox` into the `Disposed` event handler.

My question is this:

Is it necessary to detach the event handlers to ensure that the memory is cleaned up and that there are not memory leaks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an event *publisher* is being garbage collected, then there's no need to unsubscribe. You only need to unsubscribe from events if the event *subscriber* (the target of the handler delegate) needs to become eligible for garbage collection before the publisher does.